# Show or hide table column of dynamically added rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a table with some hidden columns that I need to show when the user clicks a button. The table is then fed with other data when clicking elsewhere on the page. So basically I have a table which can be populated later on.

I've managed to do the job using jQuery's toggle, but the problem is that newly added rows will keep the original css property, being hidden.

```
<style>
.hidden { display: none;}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
<th>test</th>
<th class="hidden">you cannot see me</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test</td>
<td class="hidden">you cannot see me</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button onclick="$('.hidden').toggle()">
<button onclick="addrow ()">
```

forgive any typo or syntax error.

The first time I click the button the hidden column is shown.

If I then click addrow, the newly added row has the ORIGINAL display:none, so I get row 1 expanded, and row 2 hidden.

How can I have new rows be of the last display state?

Comment: can you show us the code of the `addrow()` function. Also I would drop that inline JS for readability / maintainability.

Comment: Why not just use jQuery to fetch the visibility of the previous row's `.hidden` cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding a check into the php code generating the new rows.
upon new-row click I pass to the post if the lines should appear hidden or shown. In the latter case, I add a style="display:table-row;" to the .hidden cells, so they already appear visible on the table.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the inline JS.

I've added a data attribute to the toggle button (can also be done by just checking the already placed cells, but I think this would better if you ever want to add other functionality).

**HTML**

```
<style>
.hidden { display: none;}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
<th>test</th>
<th class="hidden">you cannot see me</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test</td>
<td class="hidden">you cannot see me</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button class="toggle" data-state="off">
<button class="add-row">
```

**JS**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('state') == 'off') {
      $(this).data('state', 'on')
    } else {
      $(this).data('state', 'off')
    }
    $('.hidden').toggle();
  });

  $('add-row').click(function() {
    // code that adds the row

    if ($('.toggle').data('state') == 'on') {
      $('.hidden').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: this is a good solution, but I'd have liked to add the rows already visible or not, to avoid confusion to the user, or rows that would appear hidden or not.